# Updating text color of all HTML items using JavaScript In Certain Conditions

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to update all black text in an html document using Javascript.

See the following:

```
const h = document.querySelector('html');
  h.style.backgroundColor = '#23272a';

var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
    if (all[i].style.color == 'rgb(0, 0, 0)') {
      all[i].style.color = "#ffffff";
    }
  }
```

The first part updating html background color works fine. However, the second part updating the text color is not working. What's going wrong here?

Comment: Please show your HTML and CSS. `style.color` is very likely nothing because color is a computed style -- try printing that before assuming it's a string like `"rgb(0, 0, 0)"`. Are you only trying to turn black text to white? As an aside, I'd apply background coloring to `body`, not `html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

> The Window.getComputedStyle() method returns an object containing the values of all CSS properties of an element, after applying active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain. Individual CSS property values are accessed through APIs provided by the object, or by indexing with CSS property names.

```js
const allElements = [...document.getElementsByTagName("*")];
allElements.forEach(el => {

  if (getComputedStyle(el).color === "rgb(0, 0, 0)") {
    el.style.color = "#ff0000";
  }
})
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Again</li>
  <li>Again</li>
  <li>Again</li>
  <li>Again</li>
  <li>Again</li>
  <li>Again</li>
  <ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second part of the code only checks for the `color: rgb(0, 0, 0)` in the `style` property.

```js
// Let's use paragraphs as an example
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
  if (all[i].style.color == 'rgb(0, 0, 0)') {
    all[i].style.color = "#ffffff";
  }
}
```

```css
.panel {
  background-color: #474b4e;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}

.black {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <p style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">rgb(0, 0, 0)</p>

  <p class="black">.black</p>
  
  <p>Default</p>
</div>
```

You can use the [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) method to get the computed `color` and make the changes accordingly

```js
// Let's use paragraphs as an example
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
  if ( getComputedStyle( all[i] ).color == 'rgb(0, 0, 0)') {
    all[i].style.color = "#ffffff";
  }
}
```

```css
.panel {
  background-color: #474b4e;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}

.black {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <p style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">rgb(0, 0, 0)</p>

  <p class="black">.black</p>
  
  <p>Default</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

using `document.querySelectorAll` will select all the HTML elements

then by looping it will update all elements, by putting inline styles on it.

```js
const h = document.querySelector('html');
  h.style.backgroundColor = '#23272a';

const all = document.querySelectorAll("*");
all.forEach(q => q.style.color = '#fff')
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <p>First paragraph</p>
    <p style="color: rgb(0,0 ,0)">Second paragraph </p>
    <p style="color: rgb(0,0 ,0)">Third paragraph </p>
    <p>Fourth paragraph</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: James, this works great for updating all text across the document. However, I am trying to target only text that is currently black, either by default or custom set. If a p had `color: rgb(0,0,1)` for example, it should not be affected.

Comment: @cappycap if that's the case then you need to loop through all text element and put it a condition where if their style.color == 'rgb(0, 0, 1)' then we will update it